# Firebase test lab reading SMS that are country specific

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to find if Firebase is able to recieve a real SMS on a physical device use the code in that SMS with my application.

So to explain a bit more, once a user register with my app they recieve a text message containing a one time code that they need to input into the application. I would like to test this part of the application but i can't find if it's possible with Firebase so I would appricate any input or alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The devices in Firebase Test Lab do not have SIM cards, and therefore do not have phone numbers and can not receive SMS messages.  So, what you're trying to do isn't possible.  You would have to code a special path through you app that bypasses SMS or uses some other mechanism.